# alternative to rebasing pushed commits

Tags: git, dvcs, rebase

The [GitHub documentation](http://learn.github.com/p/rebasing.html) recommends against rebasing commits that have been pushed publicly.

We have two branches `master` and `dev`. I have made a change to `master` for a hotfix that I would like to take across to `dev`, `dev` itself is fairly far ahead of `master`.

In this case the hotfix is to 2 files and is only a 1 line change in each.

What is the easiest way to get this to the `dev` branch without confusing things terribly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hotfix is the only thing in `master` that isn't in `dev` you could simply merge `master` into your `dev` branch.

Otherwise, you'd probably want to just cherry pick that hotfix commit into your `dev` branch. Assuming that the hotfix is the latest commit in `master` you could just do:

```
git checkout dev
git cherry-pick master
```

Comment: yeah its the only thing in master not in dev